# How to access files in a subdirectory in python?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, directory, operating-system

I am running a Jupyter Notebook Script. In the directory that that the notebook is in, is a folder that contains another folder that contains 10 folders with some images in those folders. I want to bring all of those images into my script and store them as a variable. How do I access the images?

The operation that will be performed on each image, With i being each image:

```
images = tensor([Image.open(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

you should work relatively. define a function that read all images from root folder and call it with relative path get_images('./')

```
def get_images(root):
    paths=[]
    for rootdir, subFolders, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(rootdir, filename)
            try:
                i = Image.open(file_path)
                paths.append(i)
            except IOError:
                pass

    return paths
```